# Cascaded Filter Output Not Correct

Tags: ltspice, low-pass, band-pass, high-pass-filter

I am simulating a speaker system with tweeter, woofer, and midrange speakers. I know my values for the components are all correct, but the output plot is a little off. The passbands should be a little below 0dB, but are at -20dB. The phase angle plots are correct though. Below is a screenshot of my circuit and the graph. Please help as to why this isn't working.

[image: Below is a screenshot of my circuit and the graph]

Comment: What you are plotting is the current for each Resistor. And the current is divided between your 3 branches here. You should plot voltage instead.

Comment: @HervéGrabas, the current isn't divided between the branches since the filter passbands don't overlap (much). But the resistor value is 8 ohms, meaning 0.125 A delivered when each filter is ideally passing the signal. 20*log10(0.125) is -18 dBA.

Comment: @ThePhoton agreed +1

Answer (score 2):

The dB scale on the graph in LTSpice is relative to 1 V when measuring voltages or 1 A when measuring currents.

Your resistor values are 8 ohms, so 0.125 A AC is flowing through them in the pass-band of the associated filter

$$20\log_{10}{\frac{0.125\ {\rm A}}{1\ {\rm A}}} = -18.06\ {\rm dBA}$$

I'll bet if you put a marker on your graph, you'll find this is the value being reported.

> how could I keep the resistors at 8 Ohms (it is required for the project), but get the passband to be closer to 0dB?

There are lots of ways to do this:

- Plot the voltage across R1 instead of the current through it (hat tip to Herve Grabas, in comments)
- Plot `I(R1)*8` instead of `I(R1)`
- Set the magnitude of V1 to 8 V
- Plot `I(R1)/I(V1)`
- Replace V1 with a current source with magnitude 1 A.

The main issue is that LTSpice is sloppy. It's not really plotting a gain in dB. It's plotting a current or voltage in dBA or dBV.

Comment: how could I keep the resistors at 8 Ohms (it is required for the project), but get the passband to be closer to 0dB?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what this output means. In short, your passband is at 0dB, LTspice is just displaying it weirdly. Try measuring the voltage instead of the current!

Comment: How can I plot the voltage across R1 instead of the current through it?

Comment: Click on the wire instead of the component.

Comment: @Felthry LTspice displays it accurately. What's weird is the user's interpretation. Or expectation.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, LTSpice displays it accurately but doesn't explain clearly what it is plotting or label its graph accurately. This causes lots of confusion for users who expect (reasonably) a dB scale to represent a ratio of powers. It would be more clear if they labeled the axis with 'dBA' or 'dBV' as appropriate.